# Joom!Fish issiue:Not showing all the translated articles in frontend

Tags: joomla2.5, joomfish

hello everyone
i have a multilangual site with joomla 2.5.9 and Joom!Fish 2.5.1
The problem is that Joom!Fish is not showing all the articles in the frontend and thats not only for the translated ones but for that in the original language to.
This is the [site](http://cci.al/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=114&Itemid=596&lang=en) and the menu is a category blog with the option tho show 20 articles but it doesn't show and i have more than 20 in there

Answer (score 0):

Is this still an issue? If yes, are all your joomfish plugins published and ordered as they should be, also native joomla languagefilter plugin and module need to be disabled

Comment: This should be made in comments